# Why does ASP.net Identity's IdentityDbContext have a dependency on SQL Server?

Tags: asp.net-identity-2

If you look in the source there's a solid `SqlCommand` in there. (Why do I need to even look in the source to find this out?)

Doesn't this in part defeat the point of using Entity Framework. i.e. to abstract away the database?

Couldn't they have a least made the bits that need raw SQL pluggable so that they could be replaced with for example a Postgresql implementation?

Comment: Link to the exact usage in code?

Comment: It uses SqlCommands to create the tables that Identity uses. Its the principle though. An EF database context implies that you can use any compatible provider but in this case its tied to MSSQL.

Comment: There's no `SqlCommand` in here https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/IdentityDbContext.cs The only `builder.ForSqlServer().UseIdentity();` statement is a temporary bug fix they are planning to solve it.

Comment: How about the base class?

Comment: I'm not sure now. When I go to definition using Resharper on IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> there's a method on IdentityDbContext<TUser> called VerifyColumns that takes a SqlCommand.